# Trouble with FavouriteGameButton: Icon not reflecting mutation result

Tags: reactjs, graphql, frontend, mutation

I'm facing an issue with the Favourite Game button component. When a user tries to favorite or unfavorite a game, the icon doesn't update immediately based on the mutation result. Can anyone offer some insights or help me find a solution to this problem? Thank you!

GamePageTop.tsx that will import FavouriteGameButton: receives a gameId prop and checks if there's a logged-in user. If there is, it fetches the user data and extracts the favorite games.

```
type Props = {
  gameId: string;
};

export const GamePageTop: FC<Props> = ({ gameId }) => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  if (!user) {
    return null;
  }
  const [{ data: userData }] = useUserQuery({
    variables: { userId: user.id },
  });
  const favouriteGame = userData?.user?.favouriteGame.map((it) => it.game.id);
  return (
    <FavouriteGameButton
      gameId={gameId}
      isFavourite={favouriteGame?.includes(gameId) || false}
    />
  );
};
```

FavouriteGameButton.tsx that receives the gameId and isFavourite prop. Inside the component, it uses the updateFavouriteGameMutation to handle the user's favorite/unfavorite action.

```
type Props = {
  gameId: string;
  isFavourite: boolean;
};
export const FavouriteGameButton: FC<Props> = ({ gameId, isFavourite }) => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const [, updateFavouriteGame] = useUpdateFavouriteGameMutation();
  if (!user) {
    return null;
  }
  const handleUpdateFavouriteGame = async () => {
    await updateFavouriteGame({
      userId: user.id,
      gameId: gameId,
      action: isFavourite ? "remove" : "add",
    });
  };
  return (
    <ButtonComponent
      size={"normal"}
      hovercolor="transparent"
      backgroundcolor="transparent"
      padding="0px"
      onClick={() => {
        handleUpdateFavouriteGame();
      }}
    >
      {isFavourite ? (
        <Icon icon={"starFill"} size="M" color={Colors.TagText} />
      ) : (
        <Icon icon={"starOutline"} size="M" color={Colors.TagText} />
      )}
    </ButtonComponent>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple choices.

1. You can *refetch* your `useUserQuery` query when your `updateFavouriteGame` mutation completes. Refetching is an option of a mutation operation.
2. You can treat `isFavourite` as state at the level of your `GamePageTop` component, pass the `setState` function for that state down to the `FavouriteGameButton` component, and then update that state when your query completes.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! You are right, I managed to do it by refetching useUserQuery!